# Why is MySQL result OK when called from browser, but empty or NULL when called from C#?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, null

I'm trying to do a webrequest from my C# Windows application to my website,
but the desired result is empty or null when called only from C# but not from website where it works as expected.

Before I do my request, I need to begin with a `login request` which works as expected and does indeed return the correct value.

**IMPORTANT EDIT:**

I tried to copypaste my `PHP` code in to my `login.php` file and it does work in C# and returns the correct count-value.

Is my `HttpClient` not properly configured maybe?

---

My `PHP` test code looks as following:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){ header("Location: index.php"); }

    include_once 'dbconnect.php'; //contains $db

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable"; //contains two rows
    $sql_res = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $proxyCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql_res);
    $echo "Count: ".$proxyCount;
?>
```

And my `C#` looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;

using ModernHttpClient;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void log(string str)
        {
            logbox.AppendText(str + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        private string host = "http://www.mywebsite.com/";
        private HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
        private async Task<string> request(string target, Dictionary<string, string> _parameters)
        {
            string uri = host + target;

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new FormUrlEncodedContent(_parameters)))
                return new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()).ReadToEnd();

        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string loginResp = await request("login.php", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "username", "user" }, { "password", "password" } });
            log(loginResp); 



        }

        private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string proxiesResp = await request("proxy/proxy.php", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "getAllProxyRequests", "" } });
            //above returns "count: " in C#, but returns  "count: 2" in webbrowser
            log(proxiesResp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling your url `http://www.mywebsite.com/` from Fiddler or PostMan to see if you get results?

Comment: @CodingYoshi sorry for wasting your time. I found the problem.

Comment: No worries. I always test stuff with Fiddler or a similar tool before I write a single line of code for this sort of thing. Once I know that part works, then I  write the code. Glad you solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, it was human error.

I had the file `dbconnect.php` located one directory below where `myProblem.php` was located.

I had to change the line saying

```
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
```

to

```
include_once '../dbconnect.php';
```